# Adjust the layout of table when in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my site I have a table which I've done here: https://jsfiddle.net/stw4jyq8/

```css
table {
  width: 600px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;
}

th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 90%;
  bottom-border: 2px solid #111111;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: left;
}

tr.even {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #c3e6e5;
}
```

```html
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Per 4 Pack(200G)</th>
    <th>Per 100g</th>
    <th>Per Buttery(50G)</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Calories</th>
    <td>724</td>
    <td>362</td>
    <td>181</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="even">
    <th>Fat</th>
    <td>43.1g</td>
    <td>21.6g</td>
    <td>10.8g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Saturated</th>
    <td>15.7g</td>
    <td>7.9g</td>
    <td>3.9g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="even">
    <th>Sodium</th>
    <td>1,941.9mg</td>
    <td>971mg</td>
    <td>485.5mg</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Carbohydrates</th>
    <td>78.6g</td>
    <td>39.3g</td>
    <td>19.7g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="even">
    <th>Fiber</th>
    <td>0g</td>
    <td>0g</td>
    <td>0g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Sugar</th>
    <td>10.9g</td>
    <td>5.5g</td>
    <td>2.7g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="even">
    <th>Protein</th>
    <td>10.5g</td>
    <td>5.3g</td>
    <td>2.6g</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It looks fine when being viewed on a laptop but it doesn't look great when in mobile view. What I'm looking to do is that when I'm in mobile view it will change to something like:

[image]

and then underneath it will be a separate table for per 100g and then a 3rd for per buttery if that makes sense?

For this I am not sure how I could go about that though, would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

I'm thinking this is the best direction to go with? Unless someone has a better idea? Thanks again.

Comment: Having 3 tables could definitely work, but it will make your page pretty long. Another solution might be to have a dropdown allowing the user to pick a quantity. You then might even remember the last selected value, so if the user is looking at other products as well, it is easier to compare.
Another solution you might wanna give a try, is having the left column fixed and then the other 3 scrollable or even with buttons (arrows) to easily switch from one column to the other.

Comment: If you're not against using any external libraries, I suggest you take a look at using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) if you haven't already. It offers great flexibility to make your tables responsive.

Comment: Bootstrap mostly sets the point at which the table scrolls in a container. It doesn't do anything like what's requested here.

Comment: @VincentBitter the dropdown option sounds pretty good, do you happen to have any links to an example for that?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. You're not going to be able to restructure your table with CSS. You can show and hide columns using media queries, for example, but that would require you to put the markup in the page several times in order to show multiple tables for mobile. You'll need to decide what's the best solution for your users and revise to ask something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first lead, and despite agreeing with the suggestions for a select box, here's how you would have to do it with 3 tables for mobile:

- Show your table as you did, but set a class to the columns to ease hiding them and styling them in general
- Repeat your table 2 more times with only one data column each time (per 100g, per buttery)
- Hide those 2 additional tables on large screens (by default) using CSS
- Use a media query to trigger the changes:

  - Hide 3rd and 4th columns in your large table
  - Show both mobile tables
  - Adjust widths for better display

*You can see the change in display in the below snippet by adjusting your window size*

```css
table.main {
  width: 600px;
}

table.mobile {
  display: none;
}

table.composition {
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;
}

th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 90%;
  bottom-border: 2px solid #111111;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #c3e6e5;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table.main .per-50g {
    display: none;
  }
  table.main .per-100g {
    display: none;
  }
  
  table.mobile {
    display: table;
  }
  
  table.composition {
    width: 100%;
  }

  table.composition td {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="main composition">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Per 4 Pack(200G)</th>
    <th class="per-100g">Per 100g</th>
    <th class="per-50g">Per Buttery(50G)</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Calories</th>
    <td>724</td>
    <td class="per-100g">362</td>
    <td class="per-50g">181</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Fat</th>
    <td>43.1g</td>
    <td class="per-100g">21.6g</td>
    <td class="per-50g">10.8g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Saturated</th>
    <td>15.7g</td>
    <td class="per-100g">7.9g</td>
    <td class="per-50g">3.9g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Sodium</th>
    <td>1,941.9mg</td>
    <td class="per-100g">971mg</td>
    <td class="per-50g">485.5mg</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Carbohydrates</th>
    <td>78.6g</td>
    <td class="per-100g">39.3g</td>
    <td class="per-50g">19.7g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Fiber</th>
    <td>0g</td>
    <td class="per-100g">0g</td>
    <td class="per-50g">0g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Sugar</th>
    <td>10.9g</td>
    <td class="per-100g">5.5g</td>
    <td class="per-50g">2.7g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Protein</th>
    <td>10.5g</td>
    <td class="per-100g">5.3g</td>
    <td class="per-50g">2.6g</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="mobile per-100g composition">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th class="per-100g">Per 100g</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Calories</th>
    <td class="per-100g">362</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Fat</th>
    <td class="per-100g">21.6g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Saturated</th>
    <td class="per-100g">7.9g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Sodium</th>
    <td class="per-100g">971mg</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Carbohydrates</th>
    <td class="per-100g">39.3g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Fiber</th>
    <td class="per-100g">0g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Sugar</th>
    <td class="per-100g">5.5g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Protein</th>
    <td class="per-100g">5.3g</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="mobile per-50g composition">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th class="per-50g">Per Buttery(50G)</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Calories</th>
    <td class="per-50g">181</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Fat</th>
    <td class="per-50g">10.8g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Saturated</th>
    <td class="per-50g">3.9g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Sodium</th>
    <td class="per-50g">485.5mg</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Carbohydrates</th>
    <td class="per-50g">19.7g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Fiber</th>
    <td class="per-50g">0g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Sugar</th>
    <td class="per-50g">2.7g</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Protein</th>
    <td class="per-50g">2.6g</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You could use some javascript to duplicate the table, if that suits your use case.

Comment: Thank you! That works great, I think I will look into the select box option as well, however I will still obviously accept your answer as it does answer my question :)